# Is it who, whom or, that?

Tags: that, whom, who, who-that

For the phrase, "... more than those `that` have come before." what is most correct? Is it who, whom or, that?

Comment: Please write the full sentence, not a fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whom should be used to refer to the object of a verb or preposition. When in doubt, try this simple trick: If you can replace the word with “he”’ or “’she,” use who. If you can replace it with “him” or “her,” use whom.

Who should be used to refer to the subject of a sentence.
Whom should be used to refer to the object of a verb or preposition.

Comment: Additionally, when referring to people, the use of "that" is not appropriate.